Possible to simplify this integral?
Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^N$ be a positive real sequence. Is it possible to simplify the following integral
$$
I_{n, N} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_{m=1}^N (1 + 2t a_m)}} \frac{a_n}{1 + 2t a_n} \,\mathrm{d}t \,  \quad \mbox{for}~n \leq N?  
$$
In the case $N = 2$, we have with direct calculation that
$$
I_{n, 2} = \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\sqrt{a_1} + \sqrt{a_2}}, \quad \mbox{for}~ n \leq 2.
$$

Note that $I_{n,N}$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
I_{n,N}
&= \frac{2a_n}{\pi^{N/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \, x_n^{2} e^{-\sum_{m=1}^{N} (1+2ta_m) x_m^2} \\
&= \frac{2a_n}{\pi^{N/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \, \frac{x_n^{2}}{\sum_{m=1}^{N} 2a_m x_m^2} e^{-\sum_{m=1}^{N} x_m^2} \\
&= \frac{2a_n}{\pi^{N/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}r \, r^{N-1}e^{-r^2} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{N-1}} \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega} \, \frac{\omega_n^{2}}{\sum_{m=1}^{N} 2a_m \omega_m^2} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\frac{N}{2})a_n}{\pi^{N/2}} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{N-1}} \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega} \, \frac{\omega_n^{2}}{\sum_{m=1}^{N} 2a_m \omega_m^2} \\
&= \mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\omega}\sim\text{Uniform}(\mathbb{S}^{N-1})}\biggl[ \frac{a_n \omega_n^{2}}{\sum_{m=1}^{N} a_m \omega_m^2} \biggr].
\end{align*}
As far as know, an integral of a rational function on a hypersphere cannot be written in an elementary close form for $N \geq 3$ in general, except for some special cases where $a_m$'s contain enough repetitions:

Example. When $N = 3$ and $(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (1, 2, 2)$, we have
$$ I_{1,N} = \sqrt{2} \operatorname{arsinh}(1) - 1, \qquad
I_{2,N} = I_{3,N} = 1 - \frac{\operatorname{arsinh}(1)}{\sqrt{2}}. $$

Just for fun, $I_{n,N}$ can also be written as
\begin{align*}
I_{n,N}
&= a_n \frac{\partial}{\partial a_n} \mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\omega}\sim \text{Uniform}(\mathbb{S}^{N-1})} \biggl[ \log \biggl( \sum_{m=1}^{N} a_m \omega_m^2 \biggr) \biggr]
\end{align*}

"As far as [I] know, an integral of a rational function on a hypersphere cannot be written in an elementary close form for $N \geq 3$ in general" -- would you be able to provide a reference to this fact?

@DrewBrady, This statement is mostly based on my experience with tens of other similar integrals. It is not ungrounded, though, because your integral with $N=3$ and general $a_i$'s reduces to an elliptic integral, which is proved to be non-elementary.
